# Show Merge-History before Committing

Tags: svn, merge, revision-history

`svn log` has a `--use-merge-history` option that shows all revisions that are part of the merge.

How can I get the same information for the merges in my working copy, before I commit?

E.g. after I run `svn merge ...` (sync merge) but before I run `svn ci` I want to see and summarize the logs for the commit message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Unfortunately, the command line tools apparently do not support this use case directly. However, you can write a script, that uses the output of `svn mergeinfo` and feeds it to `svn log` to get this information. The following bash script might be a good starting point.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
source="^/trunk"
url="$( svn info | sed -ne '/^URL: /s///p' )"
mergeinfo=(svn mergeinfo --show-revs=merged "$source")
revs=($( diff <( "${mergeinfo[@]}" ) <( "${mergeinfo[@]}" "$url" ) |
        sed -ne '/^< r\([0-9]\+\)$/s//-c \1/p' |
        tac ))
[[ -n "$revs" ]] &&
svn log "${revs[@]}" "$source"
```

**Update:** The tricky part is to find out, which revisions have been merged in the working copy, and have not been committed. The above script solved this problem in the following way: First it determines all revisions, which have been merged in the working directory - including both committed and uncommitted merges. Second, it determines all committed merges. And finally it calculates the difference of these two sets.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Shouldn't it be `--show-revs=eligible` though?

Comment: @hcris: `--show-revs=merged` worked in my case - if at least one revision has been merged.

Comment: I'd accept your answer though `--show-revs=merged` shows me what I have already merged and I am looking for what I am about to merge (eligible). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @hcris: I have updated the answer to explain what's happening. I suppose you have missed the `diff` in the above script.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are doing this as `--show-revs=eligible` appears to give me the correct revisions without having to do a diff.

Comment: @hcris: `--show-revs=eligible` does not work, if you merged only specific versions (i.e. _cherry-pick_), of if something else has been committed to the trunk since the merge operation.